# Qml integrated with qtwidgets, Map and coordinate update

Tags: c++, qml, qtwidgets

I'm trying to use QML embadded with QTWIDGTES.
I created a simple file in QML.
In the cpp file I want to change the coordinates and update the video map.
I've tried different ways but none seem to work.
Can you help me on what is the exact procedure?

I created a simple file in QML.

```
Item {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    Location 
    {
        id: mapCentre
        coordinate 
        {
            latitude: -10.5
            longitude: 153.1
        }
    }

    Plugin 
    {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map 
    {
        objectName: "mappazza"
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin

        center: mapCentre.coordinate

        zoomLevel: 12

        function recenter(lat,lng)
        {
            console.log(center)
            //                  center.latitude = lat
            //                  center.longitude = lng
            //update();

            map.center = QtPositioning.coordinate(lat, lng)
            mapCentre.coordinate.latitude = lat
            mapCentre.coordinate.longitude = lng
            console.log(center)
            map.update()
        }
    }

}
```

In the cpp file I do this:

```
bool SAIQMap::setCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate coordinate)
{
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, m_quickWidget->source());
    QObject *object = component.create();
    qDebug() << "Property value:" << QQmlProperty::read(object, "someNumber").toInt();

    qDebug() << object->property("lat");

    object->setProperty("lat",coordinate.latitude());
    object->setProperty("lng",coordinate.longitude());

    qDebug() << object->property("lat");

    QObject mappa = object->findChild<QQuickItem >("mappazza");

     if(mappa != NULL)
     {
         QVariant returnedValue;
         QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mappa, "recenter",
         Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue),
         Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(coordinate.latitude())),
         Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(coordinate.longitude()))
                                   );
         qDebug() << "found map";
     }

     m_quickWidget->update();

//    QQmlProperty::write(object,"coord",coordinate.toString());

    return true;
}

SAIQMap *map = new SAIQMap();
    map->init();
    map->setFixedSize(450,200);
    UI->layoutMappa->addWidget(map);

    map->setCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(39.65346596074623, 12.191204177530357));
```

The code enters the recentr function and changes the coordinates.
But the video doesn't change, it remains positioned with the initialization coordinates.
I've tried different ways but none seem to work.
Can you help me on what is the exact procedure?